# How should we refer to other examples or topics under the same documentation tag?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Say we have an example of a fairly complex set of code, and it makes extensive use of something that is heavily documented in another example. What is the correct way to refer to this other example?

The ways I could think of would be:

- Paraphrasing, and mentioning it's explained elsewhere.
- Linking, and not reiterating.
- Re-explaining any immediately applicable parts of the code shown in examples.

Comment: Excellent question. Shocking that it has to be asked and isn't intuitive in existing UI,  or by being able to peruse documented examples

Comment: I actually assumed it had been covered initially, but after searching for it I couldn't find anything. I half expected the first comment to be a link to an existing conversation about this...

Comment: lots of similar issues where the system isn't robust enough , the UI isn't intuitive and documentation is non existent. Lots of frustration across the board

Comment: I would think it would be like Q&A; explain what is in the linked resource that is relevant, and add a link. The link should not be necessary, but should be useful for deeper understanding. There's a Share button next to every example from which you can get the URL.

Answer (score 3):

To start...I don't have the answer of how to properly crosslink examples.

I just have a very related add-on question. :-)

**Eventually...**

Crosslinks are important parts of good documentation so I assume as the doc system becomes more robust there will eventually become a more obvious way of crosslinking Examples within the same Topic or even crosslinking of Examples across Topics.

**Currently...**

You can post a Topic + multiple Examples as a draft.

Each draft Example has a unique draft url.

**Question:**

If we want to crosslink draft Examples should we use the **draft** Example's url?

That is (attention SO web-devs) ... May we assume that when a draft goes live that any draft links will be auto-magically converted to where the live Example lives?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a corollary to this question is how to reference original content outside of SO-Docs and **not** copy (potentially) copyrighted content. It's quite interesting that [Microsoft is joining in on SO-Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/teamblog/stackoverflow-documentation-for-microsoft-developers/) so whole-heartedly (though the end result remains to be seen).

With the intent of SO-Docs serving as a quick reference point for many language, methodology, and usage questions, it is easily possible that a definitive description or example set is available outside of SO/SO-Docs. I submitted an example in [vba-excel] to this effect, but only provided a brief description and a link to this definitive content. I'm all for home-brewing original content on SO-Docs, but sometimes it can't get any better.

I'm very happy to receive guidance on this myself (and my posted example if you like), but wanted to expand the question on examples by adding to @markE's response above.